# Need help in describing what the function does overall

Tags: python

```
def mystery2(surname):
  num = 0
  for i in range (0,len(surname)):
    if surname[i].find("-")>-1:
       num = num+1
  return float(num) / len(surname)
```

I roughly get the `for` loop where its getting something to do with the length of the surname and finding whether there is a `'-'` in the string but the rest I need help.

Comment: So what have you done to figure it out? Tried calling it to see what output you get? Tried to run little bits of it in the interpreter? This is trivial code, and the function name suggests that somebody has asked you to work out what it does - so why should we do that for you?

Comment: First step is to look up what each of the functions in there do.  Look up `range`, `len`, `find`, and `float`.  Then try to work out on paper or in your head what the function does, step by step, for an example input `surname`.

Comment: Hello jonrsharpe, i have tested out the code but it gives me an error. and i have tried my best to understand what it does but to no avail. hoping someone could help

Comment: @Ashinaku what error? The code runs fine for me. It's not very well written, but certainly not hard to understand.

Comment: Thanks guys for your input. I have thus figured what it does! LOL it was pretty easy and i was blind folded not to see it. Tada

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To test the function you can either:

1. Run an interactive Python interpreter and paste the code into it, or
2. Create a file, e.g. named `mystery2.py` containing the code, then run `python -i mystery2.py`.

Either of the above will define the function within your interactive environment. Now you can start trying out some invocations of the function and use the results to infer its purpose:

```
>>> mystery2("smith-jones")
0.09090909090909091
>>> mystery2("no hyphen")
0.0
>>> mystery2("----")
1.0
>>> mystery2("abcd----")
0.5
>>> mystery2(["first-name", "second----------name", "-", "no hyphen"])
0.75
>>> mystery2("")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/m.py", line 6, in mystery2
    return float(num) / len(surname)
ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero

>>> mystery2([])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/m.py", line 6, in mystery2
    return float(num) / len(surname)
ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero
```